# How do I call method inside map::find() after converting from iterator-based for-loop?

Tags: c++

I would like to convert my existing for-loop map to use map.find().

As seen below the `WeatherTree.search` checks against the year variable but `WeatherMap` also checks against the same year variable.

The below portion of the map is found in Menu.cpp.

```cpp
    if(WeatherTree.search(year))
    {
        for (itr = WeatherMap.begin(); itr != WeatherMap.end(); itr++)
        {
            if(itr->first == year)
            {
                for(auto itr2 = itr->second.begin(); itr2 != itr->second.end(); itr2++)
                {
                    if(itr2->GetMonth() == month)
                    {
                        wind += itr2->GetWind();
                        temperature += itr2->GetTemperature();
                        count++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

What I would like to do instead is `WeatherTree.search` continue to check against year variable while `WeatherMap` using `find()` check against month. `WeatherTree` is a binary search tree (BST) but it is not important as my question is about STL map. The `WeatherMap` is also index using month rather than year.

**But how do I call the `GetWind()` and `GetTemperature()` and also what about the count which will be use for calculating average later.**

I have Google they mostly return what the cpp documentation is showing which is not I wanted.

```cpp
WeatherMap[W.GetMonth()].insert(W);

if(WeatherTree.search(year))
{
    auto itr = WeatherMap.find(month);
    if (itr != WeatherMap.end())
    {
        wind +=
        temperature +=
        count++;
    }
}
```

**Menu.cpp**

```cpp
#include "Menu.h"

using namespace std;

Menu::Menu()
{
    Load();
}

void Menu::Load()
{
    ifstream ifile;
    string filename, line, smonth, syear, swind, stemperature, shumidity;
    cout << "Enter the filename to open" << endl;
    getline(cin, filename);
    ifile.open(filename);
    if (!ifile.is_open())
    {
        cout << "Please try again!" << endl;
        system("PAUSE");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else
    {
        getline(ifile, line);
        while (getline(ifile, line))
        {
            if (!line.empty())
            {
                istringstream istream(line);
                getline(istream, smonth, ',');
                getline(istream, syear ',');
                getline(istream, swind, ',');
                getline(istream, shumidity, ',');
                getline(istream, stemperature, '\n');

                int month = stoi(smonth);
                int year = stoi(syear);
                double wind = stod(swind);
                int humidity = stoi(shumidity);
                double temperature = stod(stemperature);

                Weather W;
                W.SetWeather(month, year, wind, humidity, temperature);
                WeatherMap[W.GetYear()].insert(W);
                WeatherTree.insert(W.GetYear());
            }
        }
        ifile.close();
    }
}

void Menu::Options()
{
    int options = 0;

    while(options != 3)
    {
        cout << "1) Average wind speed and temperature of a month and year" << endl;
        cout << "2) Average humidity of a year" << endl;
        cout << "3) Quit" << endl;
        cin >> options;

        switch(options)
        {
            case 1:
                FirstOption();
                break;
            case 2:
                SecondOption();
                break;
            case 3:
                cout << "Goodbye!" << endl;
                break;
            default:
                cout << "Invalid input" << endl;
                break;
        }
    }
}

void Menu::FirstOption()
{
    int month = 0;
    int year = 0;
    int count = 0;
    double wind = 0.0;
    double temperature = 0.0;
    Weather W2;
    map<int, set<Weather>>::iterator itr;

    cout << "Enter month" << endl;
    cin >> month;
    cout << "Enter year" << endl;
    cin >> year;

    if(WeatherTree.search(year))
    {
        for (itr = WeatherMap.begin(); itr != WeatherMap.end(); itr++)
        {
            if(itr->first == year)
            {
                for(auto itr2 = itr->second.begin(); itr2 != itr->second.end(); itr2++)
                {
                    if(itr2->GetMonth() == month)
                    {
                        wind += itr2->GetWind();
                        temperature += itr2->GetTemperature();
                        count++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (wind != 0 || temperature != 0 || wind < 0 || temperature < 0)
    {
        cout << W2.GetAvg(wind, count) << "km/h" << W2.GetAvg(temperature, count) << "degree celsius" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "No information" << endl;
    }
}
```

**Weather.cpp**

```cpp
#include "Weather.h"

using namespace std;

Weather::Weather()
{
    wind = 0;
    humidity = 0;
    temperature = 0;
}

int Weather::GetMonth()
{
    return month;
}

int Weather::GetYear()
{
    return year;
}

double Weather::GetWind()
{
    return wind;
}

int Weather::GetHumidity()
{
    return humidity;
}

double Weather::GetTemperature()
{
    return temperature;
}

void Weather::SetMonth(int m)
{
    month = m;
}

void Weather::SetYear(int y)
{
    year = y;
}

void Weather::SetWind(double w)
{
    wind = w;
}

void Weather::SetHumidity(int h)
{
    humidity = h;
}

void Weather::SetTemperature(double t)
{
    temperature = t;
}

void Weather::SetWeather(int m, int y, double w, int h, double t)
{
    month = m;
    year = y;
    wind = w;
    humidity = h;
    temperature = t;
}

double Weather::GetAvg(double total, int count)
{
    return total / count;
}
```

Comment: you should search one certain month in `WeatherMap[year]`, which is a set of `Weather` according to your definition.

Comment: @lincr Do you mean changing `WeatherMap[W.GetYear()].insert(W);` to `WeatherMap[W.GetMonth()].insert(W);`?

Comment: Are you trying to count or find?
https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q=std%3A%3Acount+on++a+map

Comment: @Mikhail i'm trying to use find to check if the month the user enter matches/exists inside the map and the count is used to count how many data it retrieved as count is used to calculate the average of the wind speed and temperature.

Comment: @Mikhail if the month exists inside the map then it get the speed and temperature from the map and set it onto the local variable which together with the count variable is used to calculus the average speed and temperature for that month the user entered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First your should know `map::find()` works by comparing keys of the map to a given query. So you can't using `find()` to compare months since month is not the key of you map.

**Note: Possibly you don't need `WeatherTree` since you are using `year` as a key saving Weather records.**

What you can do:

Method 1:

Keep your current map definition not changed. And iterate in the corresponding Weather set once you are sure the year exists.

```
    if(WeatherMap.find(year) != WeatherMap.end())
    {
        for (auto itr = WeatherMap[year].begin(); itr != WeatherMap[year].end(); itr++)
        {
           if(itr->GetMonth() == month)
           {
               wind += itr->GetWind();
               temperature += itr->GetTemperature();
               count++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Method 2

Change your map to `map<<int, int>, W>`, i.e., using both year and month as a key.
Then you have:

```
     if (WeatherMap.find(make_pair(year, month)) != WeatherMap.end()) {
         // calculate
     }
```

Comment: Hi tks for the answer but what if I wanted to keep WeatherTree (BST) which I needed to, will the method 2 works?

Comment: Yes, you can save year in both your tree and map seperately. But note to perform some operations on both, like deleting a year or something.

Answer (score 0):

There is a while that I do not program in C++, but this could be a solution (I did not test it):

```
std::for_each(WeatherMap.begin(), WeatherMap.end(), [&](const auto& value) {
    if ( value.first == year ) {
        auto it1 = value.second.begin();
        while( (it1 = std::find_if(it1, value.second.end(), [&](const auto& item) {
                if ( item.GetMonth() == month ) {
                    ...
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
                })) != value.second.end()
              )
              it1++;
    }
}
```